# Sphere collision response

Tags: java, collision-detection, graphics

I have simple mechanism for testing of two balls colliding:

```
private static boolean isColliding(float firstBallX, float firstBallY, double firstBallRadius, float secondBallX, float secondBallY, double secondBallRadius) {
       final double a = firstBallRadius + secondBallRadius;
       final double dx = firstBallX - secondBallX;
       final double dy = firstBallY - secondBallY;
       return a * a > (dx * dx + dy * dy);
   }
```

And it works great. One of the balls is moving and the other (second one) is static. 
I have two questions.

When a collision occurs, how do I change the movement of the first ball (the moving) one to its logical path? I suppose I should change the direction somehow, but cannot figure out how...?

The other question is how do I tell the static ball, after the collision move? And what is its path, direction and staff...?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12):

Its called [elastic collision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision).

[image: from wikipedia entry]

Here are some similar questions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345838/ball-to-ball-collision-detection-and-handling
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780169/how-do-i-create-collision-detections-for-my-bouncing-balls